# url saved into a string not saving properly (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure

I currently have this in my codebehind

```
Dim PDFDirectory As String = "http://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/"
Dim PDFPath As String = PDFDirectory + UploadPDF.FileName
Dim fileNameWithoutExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(UploadPDF.FileName)
Dim iteration As Integer = 1
While System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(PDFPath))
    PDFPath = String.Concat(PDFDirectory, fileNameWithoutExtension, "-", iteration, ".pdf")
    iteration += 1
End While   

UploadPDF.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(PDFPath))
e.Values("PDF") = PDFPath
```

Basically, I'm uploading a file from my website to my azure storage which is working fine, but after uploading I want the url of that file I'm uploading to show up on my sql database.

The problem however is whenever i'm done uploading my file the url shows up as 
http:/storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/ with only one '/' after the http and so I'm getting this error

Additional information: 'http:/storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/PDFfileName.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.
(Notice how there's only one '/' instead of the two '//' that should show up after the http, also PDFfileName is the hypothetical name of the PDF that was just uploaded)

Any idea why its showing as http:/storagename instead of http://storagename?

Comment: Can you please provide all the code?  All I see is `e.Values("PDF") = PDFPath`.  What's done with `e` later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

This part

```
While System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(PDFPath))
    PDFPath = String.Concat(PDFDirectory, fileNameWithoutExtension, "-", iteration, ".pdf")
    iteration += 1
End While
```

is trying to search for the file in the local system which doesn't exist because it's a URL.

If anyone is interested here's how to check if URL already exists. (Hopefully it makes sense)

```
 Dim PDFDirectory As String = ("http://storagName.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/")

 'The URL it'll check is the PDFDirectory (URL above) + the name of the file I have on the fileupload control, which has the ID of UploadPDF
 Dim PDFPath As String = PDFDirectory + UploadPDF.FileName
 Dim fileNameWithoutExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(UploadPDF.FileName)
 Dim iteration As Integer = 1

'Check if URL already exists
 Dim urlTest As New System.Uri(PDFDirectory + UploadPDF.FileName)
 Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
 req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(urlTest)
 Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse

 Try
 'If URL already exists, PDF name will iterate like this PDFname-1.pdf and upload to Azure Storage
 resp = req.GetResponse()
 resp.Close()
 req = Nothing
 PDFPath = String.Concat(PDFDirectory, fileNameWithoutExtension, "-", iteration, ".pdf")
 iteration += 1

 Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(PDFPath)

 Using UploadPDF.PostedFile.InputStream
     blockBlob.UploadFromStream(UploadPDF.PostedFile.InputStream)
 End Using

 Catch ex As Exception
 'If URL doesn't exist then upload PDF to Azure Storage
 Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(UploadPDF.FileName)

 Using UploadPDF.PostedFile.InputStream
     blockBlob.UploadFromStream(UploadPDF.PostedFile.InputStream)
 End Using
 End Try

 'This part saves the PDFPath (the URL of the saved PDF) as a value into the SQL database column called "PDF"
 e.Values("PDF") = PDFPath

 'So in my SQL DB in the PDF column will have this value -  http://storagName.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/PDFname.pdf
 'Or if that URL already exists, it won't overwrite that url but instead have this value - http://storagName.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/PDFname-1.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I might have a slight idea why it's showing as only 1 "/" if I could look at the rest of the code... but you could always try this:

```
Dim PDFDirectory As String = "http:/" & "/storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/"
```

or even add another "/" for the sake of try

```
Dim PDFDirectory As String = "http://" & "/storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/"
```

Doesn't hurt to try :S
Once I was stuck for days, and I was missing an "\"... imagine that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put "@" before the string

example:

```
 @"http://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/pdfs/PDFfileName.pdf"
```

Comment: I believe that this only applies to C#.  The code is VB.Net.